# Xpath select between elements under condition (containing text)

Tags: html, xpath

I have a page like this (a speech or a dialogue page organised like this, so speaker name in bold and then paragraphs of his speech):

```
<body>
    <p>
        <b>
             speaker abc:
        </b>
    some wanted text here
    </p>
    <p>
         some other text wanted, maybe containing speaker abc
    </p>
    
    <p>
         some other text wanted, maybe containing speaker cde
    </p>
    
    <p>
         some other text wanted
    </p>

    <p>
        <b>
             speaker cde (can be random):
        </b>
    </p>

    <p>
         some other text UNwanted, maybe containing speaker abc
    </p>
    
    <p>
         some other text UNwanted, maybe containing speaker cde
    </p>
    
    <p>
         some other text UNwanted
    </p>

    
    <p>
        <b>
             speaker abc:
        </b>
    </p>
    
    <p>
         some other text wanted
    </p>

    <p>
        <b>
             speaker fgh:
        </b>
    </p>

    
    <p>
         some other text UNwanted
    </p>

    
</body>
```

I would like to select (using xpath) all text elements marked as wanted text in example (all phrases spoken by one particular speaker, say abc).

I am not very fluent with xpath and html, I suspect there should be some usage of axis but struggle to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to do using XPath 1.0 alone.

In XSLT 2.0+, use positional grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[b]">...</
```

and then select the groups you are interested in.

If you have to do it using XPath 1.0, consider pre-processing the input using XSLT to split the text into speeches, using xsl:for-each-group as suggested.

Comment: Is it possible at all with XPath 1.0 ?

Comment: I would hesitate to say it's impossible, but I'm not going to attempt it, because it's hard, and there are much better tools available.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath will do this:

```
"//*[preceding-sibling::p[contains(.,'speaker abc')] and following-sibling::p[contains(.,'speaker cde')]]"
```

We are limiting the wanted `p` nodes by `preceding-sibling` `p` node containing the wanted text speaker name in front and by `following-sibling` `p` node containing the next, unwanted speaker name on the end.
the output is

```
some other text wanted, maybe containing abc
some other text wanted, maybe containing cde
some other text wanted
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, I realised I haven't formulated my question properly. Actually I want to select all phrases of abc only, I do not know the names of other speakers in advance. I also do not want elements in bold as well. I think I should definitely use contains and probably not(contains) and axis as well, so a good starting point. I edited the answer